# Why does Fort Lauderdale airport Wi-Fi prevent me from submitting certain answers with code?

Tags: support, bug

I am in the Fort Lauderdale airport, waiting for a flight, and connected to the Internet on my computer, which I regularly use for Stack Overflow. The only difference is that I am connected to the publicly available Wi-Fi system.

Certain code combinations are simply not allowed. For instance, the code in [Slow MySQL Query Over Millions of Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483560/slow-mysql-query-over-millions-of-records/22484522#22484522) could not be accepted (you will see that someone else edited it after me).

Is there a way to fix this or work around it? I am logged in on a Mac using Chrome.

Edit:

Now I am in the airplane, so this is via a mobile device.

The error is simply that the answer or comment cannot be submitted. This is not a generic problem with all code. I was able to submit partially formatted code, which was then edited.

Also, simply removing the formatting did not fix the problem.

Stack Overflow *can* do something about it. The first thing would be notifying the submitter about where the error is occurring. Improved error descriptions should be entirely in the spirit of the site.

Second, if we know what the problem is, then perhaps that can be communicated to the people running such sites. Fixing the Internet is not in the purview of Stack Overflow, but on a community moderated site no one individual needs to take responsibility for it. If we know what the problem is, then just maybe it can be fixed.

Is there a way to figure out what the real problem is so such issues can be fixed?

And, I'm just happy that my flight is only 20 minutes late, so this issue no longer affects me.

(If I had missed the flight due to overuse of Stack Overflow, the site might have done me a favor. It is about 50 degrees (F) colder in New York City than down here.)

Comment: Have you tried connecting via HTTPS?

Comment: You'll have to ask the Fort Lauderdale airport, if they're the ones blocking your network traffic.

Comment: Most likely the firewall on the airport WiFi is rather dumb and prevents **any** SQL code to be transmitted. Use HTTPS or a different wifi network. Most of all, there is nothing Stack Exchange can do about this.

Comment: What does Fiddler show?

Comment: If it had let you post answers and use the site normally, you probably would have missed your flight. Even despite it being 20 minutes late.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ... If that is indeed the problem, what needs to be communicated to the site operators to fix it?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn [tag:status-bydesign] then? :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Ask them why they are using firewall filtering software that has such a huge false-positive rate for anyone doing actual database work?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: And no, Stack Exchange **cannot** do anything about firewalls altering posted data mid-transmission. There is no way for the site to detect all possible tampering along the way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters . . . Stack Exchange *could* still say where the error *is*.  I think that is something the site could and should do.

Comment: @Gordon, think of it like this. I call up my friend in Kazakhstan, but he's not available. I hear a beep and leave a message, but my friend doesn't get it because it turns out that was really the message saying that the phone is out of the service area. How exactly could my friend have told me that he was out of the service area when he doesn't even know I called in the first place? You are sending data via their connection. Their connection stops it before it gets to Stack Overflow. How can Stack Overflow tell you about what it never knew about?

Comment: @jmac . . . If *nothing* is transmitted to Stack Overflow, then I get the idea that little can be done.  However, I get the idea that *something* is transmitted but then there is a failure due to the filtering.  This is clearly not my area of expertise, so I actually do not know what gets transmitted and what doesn't.